# twitter bootstrap collapsible header - hide on load

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

does anyone know if there any way to set the collapsible header to be closed by default on page load?
When I load the page on smaller devices - i.e iphone etc - The menu is open - which pushes any content out of view.
I'd like to have it closed on load if poss.

any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: That should be the default behavior. Can you post your html so we can take a look?

Comment: thanks, yes I was wondering whether there was  an event I coulld fire to problematically close it. I guess I'll just trigger and event on the close button. Html is the same as the bootstrap demo site.http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1):

I spent few hours on the same issue, then I discovered that inline style was missing, et voilá

```
  <div class="nav-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
```

but this will not work in IE7 and IE8.. I was wrong, this is not the way to solve it. And I had not solve it yet